# Class cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, comparator

First of all, I know some people has already asked similar questions, but I'm not sure if this is the same as what they asked.

I have a class named `Vehicle` which has an attribute named `location`. On the other side, I have a class named `Road` which has an ArrayList attribute of Vehicles. I want to order the list, named `_vehicles`, using `location` but in descending order, so I created this class into the Road class:

```
class CompareVehicles implements Comparator<Vehicle> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Vehicle o1, Vehicle o2) {
        if (o1.getLocation() < o2.getLocation()) return 1;
        if (o1.getLocation() > o2.getLocation()) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And an attribute named `_vehicleComparator` which its type is `CompareVehicles`. But, when I execute the method `_vehicles.sort(_vehicleComparator)`, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class simulator.model.Vehicle cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (simulator.model.Vehicle is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
    at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1316)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1717)
    at simulator.model.Road.advance(Road.java:115)
    at simulator.model.TrafficSimulator.advance(TrafficSimulator.java:44)
    at simulator.control.Controller.run(Controller.java:54)
    at simulator.launcher.Main.startBatchMode(Main.java:136)
    at simulator.launcher.Main.start(Main.java:144)
    at simulator.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:156)
```

Should `Vehicle` implement the `Comparable` interface, even if I'm using a Comparator? Or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A comparator is not the same as comparable.

Comment: Is `_vehicleComparator` initialized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to be passing `null` to `List.sort` instead of your `Comparator`. In this case, and some others, a `null` `Comparator` is interpreted as meaning use the elements' `Comparable` interface.

Comment: True, I've just forgot to initialize it, thanks! (One extra question: CompareVehicles should be created into the Road class or outside it but in the same file?)

Comment: @Awacate I'd probably make `Vehicle` `Comparable`. I'm not a huge fan of nested classes. Multiple top-level classes in the same file is frowned upon. If I was sticking with `Comparator` I'd probably go for , a `public static final` (all of those thing) field, with the implementation as a lambda function.